# Get number for Cortana in JS Hosted Web app

Tags: javascript, uwp, cortana

I'm trying to get Cortana to work in my Hosted Web App. However, I'm stumbeling into an issue where I don't get the text the user has spoken to Cortana. Here is what should happen:

If the user says "ChangeWindows show build 14393" the app should open and navigate to the address "/build/14393". However, I'm not sure how to get that number. Here's the code I have right now:

The vcd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
    <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="ChangeWindowsPreview">
        <CommandPrefix>ChangeWindows</CommandPrefix>
        <Example>Navigate to a changelog, milestone or build</Example>

        <Command Name="OpenBuild">
            <Example>Show build 14393</Example>
            <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase">Show [build] {build}</ListenFor>
            <Feedback>Opening build {build} with ChangeWindows</Feedback>
            <Navigate />
        </Command>

        <Command Name="OpenNext">
            <Example>Show the next major release</Example>
            <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase">Show [the] next [major] [feature] [release]</ListenFor>
                <Feedback>Opening vNext with ChangeWindows</Feedback>
        <Navigate />
        </Command>

        <PhraseTopic Label="build" Scenario="Dictation"></PhraseTopic>
    </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

And for my JS I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">            
    if ( typeof Windows !== 'undefined' ) {            
        var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
        
        Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("activated", function (args) {
            if ( args.kind === activation.ActivationKind.voiceCommand ) {
                var speechRecognitionResult = args.result;

                if ( speechRecognitionResult.rulePath[0] === "OpenBuild" ) {
                    console.log( "Opening this build from Cortana: " + speechRecognitionResult.text );
                    window.location.replace( "/build/" + speechRecognitionResult.text );
                }

                if ( speechRecognitionResult.rulePath[0] === "OpenNext" ) {
                    console.log( "Opening next feature release with Cortana" );
                    window.location.replace( "/build/next" );
                }
            }
        })
}
    </script>
```

So, obviously, 'speechRecognitionResult.text' is not what I'm looking for here. I hoped someone however knows should be there to get {build}.

Comment: Why don't you use a `PhraseList` with specific items instead of `PhraseTopic`?

Comment: `PhraseLists` are only for predefined values, right? These numbers are random numbers.